# Why does movzx instruction not allow a quadword destination operand with a double-word source operand?

Tags: assembly, type-conversion, x86-64, nasm, intel

As per my understanding, MOVZX used for unsigned widening conversions, which convert smaller size (Memory | REG) to bigger size (Memory | REG) with zero-extension. It works fine when I do following conversions:

```
`movzx <reg16>, <op8>
movzx <reg32>, <op8>
movzx <reg32>, <op16>
movzx <reg64>, <op8>
movzx <reg64>, <op16>`
```

Note: Second operand can be either be REG or Memory.

But when I'm trying to perform below operation:

`movzx <reg64>, <op32>`

It fails. Why?

```
section .data
MSG1    dd 10000

section .text
global _start
_start:
    mov eax, dword[MSG1]
    movzx rbx, eax 
last:
    mov rax, 60
    xor rdi, 0
    syscall

$nasm -f elf64 sample.asm -g -l sample.lst
```

The error I am getting :

> "sample.asm:8: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands"

Comment: 32 bit operations automatically zero extend to 64 bits so you don't need that form of `movzx`. You can just do `mov ebx, eax`.

Comment: Expanding on what @jester said the automatic zero extending (which only occurs in in 64-bit mode) when a destination register is 32-bits (ie eax, ebx, esi etc) also applies when the source and destination are the same. So the instruction `mov eax, eax` may appear to do nothing at first glance in 64-bit code but it too will zero extend the result through the entire 64-bit register RAX. If the upper 32-bits of RAX were non zero before `mov eax, eax` they will be zero after.